# Attaching one object to each hand of a Mixamo action

Tags: animation

I have downloaded the Mixamo action Digging. I have modelled a shovel mesh (with no armature in it) and can parent one end to one hand. How do I parent the other end to the other hand to get the guy to dig the hole? Will I have to create bones for the shovel?

Comment: you can do the opposite: Give each hand a Child Of constraint with the shovel as Target (and click on the constraint Set Inverse button)

Comment: That does not work.

Comment: To be more precise you need to give the Child Of constraint to the lower arm IK controller

Comment: OK but all that does is let the shovel control the hands and arms. How do you get the Mixamo action to control the shovel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong but in my opinion it will be much easier to do the opposite, aka make the hands the children of the shovel, because you can't make the shovel the child of 2 different bones.

You could make the shovel child of one hand (the hand that holds the back of the shovel) and make it track to the other hand (the one in front of the shovel), but you'll constantly have to rotate the hands so that they fit with the shovel angle, while if you do the opposite, aka the shovel controlling the hands, they will always twist correctly.

In that case, and more precisely, make the hand contollers (aka the targets of your arms *IK* constraints) the children of the shovel. You just need to give a *Child Of* constraint to both the 2 hand controllers with the shovel as *Target*:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I see what you mean but remember that my question concerned a Mixamo action and your most significant point is that "you can't make the shovel the child of 2 different bones". What this means is that the otherwise excellent animation of the downloaded Mixamo Digging action (ranging over 117 frames) is in fact a mere mime because it can't operate the shovel. Thanks for the help.

Comment: is it possible for you to share the armature with its animation?

Comment: Do you mean can I let you have a look at the Mixamo download? It's in an .fbx file but I don't know how to get it to you!

Comment: I don't know mixamo but I can try to understand how it is made or maybe someone will tell, you can share here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/